# Transfer files between folders on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, file-transfer

How can I implement a method in a separate thread that performs the transfer of files between folders on Android, and after transferring this file to be deleted from the source folder?

Comment: By the time I checked there are files in my application on the Android File System default folder.

`private Boolean IsExistFiles() {
    Boolean ret = false;
    File applicationPath = new      file(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(getApplicationInfo().labelRes));

    File childs[] = applicationPath.listFiles();
  
  if(childs != null)
   ret = true;
  
  return ret;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

1. You can use AsyncTask to do something on a separate thread.
2. Think whether you wil be dealing with files in internal or external storage. If latter, you'll need to specify a permission in your manifest file.
3. A simple way of moving a file to a new location:

   `File file = new File(filename);`

   `boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(newName));`